# How to link JWT to my users info database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, user-interface, authentication, redux

I have created a web app and use Auth0 for authentication. Each user has his own page with personal data.

How can I connect an user logged via Auth0 to my Mysql database in order to retrieve and update his specific data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokens returned from Auth0 contain encoded data. When you decode it you can see for example something like this.

```
{
  "iss": "http://YOUR_DOMAIN/",
  "sub": "auth0|123456",
  "aud": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  "exp": 1311281970,
  "iat": 1311280970,
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "given_name": "Jane",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "gender": "female",
  "birthdate": "0000-10-31",
  "email": "janedoe@example.com",
  "picture": "http://example.com/janedoe/me.jpg"
}
```

This is the payload of an ID token which I copied from this [page](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens). You can connect the Auth0 user and the user data in your database by using a common unique ID. Here you could use `sub` for example. You can also use the access token. It contains the same `sub` but some of the other data is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `authToken` state in your `user` reducer & upon sign in set this `authToken` state equal to received auth0 token. Then for each subsequent request for data retrieval pass this `authToken` value to validate your request.

**reducer.js**

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  ...
  authToken = '';
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    ...
    case 'SET_AUTH_TOKEN':
      return ({
        ...state,
        authToken: action.payload
      })
  }
};
```

To persist this `authToken` for a session you can use `redux-persist` library which uses localStorage & sessionStorage to preserve redux state upon reload.